# What's the point of using such operations in this HashMap implementation?

Tags: java

There's some code from **Thinking in Java**:

```
public class SimpleHashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> {
    static final int SIZE = 997;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    LinkedList<MapEntry<K,V>>[] buckets = new LinkedList[SIZE];
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        V oldValue = null;
        int index = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % SIZE;
        if(buckets[index] == null)
            buckets[index] = new LinkedList<MapEntry<K,V>>();
        LinkedList<MapEntry<K,V>> bucket = buckets[index];
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

What's the point of the `int index = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % SIZE;` string? Why are used exactly absolute value and modulus operations?

Comment: It has to create an index for new element that is positive and within size range, that is why there is a % size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that `index` is going to be used as an array index. Therefore, using "raw" hash code is not acceptable, because the return value may be a negative number, or a positive number above `SIZE-1`.

- Absolute value is used to ensure that the number is non-negative
- Modulo is used to ensure that the index is in the range of allowed array indexes.

Of course, other ways of ensuring that the index is in the range can be developed. For example, one could compute modulo first, then add `SIZE` to negative numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a bad example, since `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` is `MIN_VALUE`, so `index` ends up being `-483`, and crashes the code. Doing `abs()` *after* the modulus operation would work, or your suggestion of adding `SIZE`. *(Maybe they should rename the book to "Not thinking in Java")* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This expression is computing an index in a fixed size array.

The index must be non-negative and less than the length of the array.

```
int index = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % SIZE;
```

The method `hashCode()` can return a value that is negative and whose absolute value exceeds the length of the array. So this code takes its absolute value, and uses the modulus operator to wrap around any excessively large value to a position in the array.

For example, consider a `hashCode()` value of -1000. The absolute value from `Math.abs()` is 1000. Then taking 1000 % SIZE (where SIZE is 997) gives you 3. So the index would be 3, pointing to the fourth bucket in the zero-based array.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a bad example, since `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` is `MIN_VALUE`, so `index` ends up being `-483`, and crashes the code. Doing `abs()` *after* the modulus operation would work, though.

Comment: @Andreas - Good point. In that case, the example above would be that -1000 % SIZE gives you -3, and `Math.abs(-3)` is 3.